# How can I declare in C sharp a List with nullable double values?

Tags: c#, mono, nullable

The purpose is to enumerate the list and count how many nullable values I have, It will be used in order to test some Linq code because I lack of database.  The thing is that no matter how I tried to define it I get from my compiler:  "The type or namespace name `List`1' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?(CS0246)]".

thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean List<double?> foo= new List<double?>()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

make sure you have:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

then it should be as easy as:

```
List<double?> mylist = new List<double?>();
```

Comment: List<> is in System.Collections.Generic, as the changed answer states :)

Comment: @jimmy, i was adding it as you were putting in this comment, @chris, what @jimmy said.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using mcs? It would be targeting the 1.1 runtime. that would explain "assembly reference not found" Try gmcs for targeting 2.0.

Of course, `using System.Collections.Generic;` is the cure for "missing  using directive"

Answer (score 2):

With John Boker's answer, you could do something like the following:

```
List<double?> mylist = new List<double?>();
int nullItemsCount = mylist.Count(item => !item.HasValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<double?> l = new List<double?>();`

Works for me... List(Of T) as is Nullable(Of T) is in System.Core do you have that referenced?